# Wordpress + GEOmyWP Plugin, customize the while loop from the search result template

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement, while-loop

i need some help.
I use Wordpress with the GEOmyWP Plugin and i want to customize the search-results template.
I want to show in the while loop first all posts with the specific term "pro" and than all other posts.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
while ( $gmw_query->have_posts() ) :
$gmw_query->the_post();

* and if has the term "pro" from the taxonomy "paket" *

?>

* Show only posts with the term "pro" *

<php elseif; ?>

* Show all other posts *

<?php endif; endwhile; ?>
```

I hope someone can help me with this little issue.

I have tried some options but nothing has worked for me...

Comment: Basically, two options: Manipulate that search query using the `pre_get_posts` filter, to include the sorting directly in there already, so that you get the results in the desired order directly from the database; or you loop over the data _twice_ in your template, and in the first loop you output all the posts with term "pro", and in the second one those without ...